# Can't add Google Webmaster metatag because "Site Verification" category is missing

Tags: 7, meta-tags, google-search-console

I'm using Drupal 7 (I can't update) and I'm trying to add Google Webmaster verification meta tag using the following instruction: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/modules/metatag/howto-verify-a-site-on-google-webmaster-tools-d7-d8
There is simply no "Site Verification" category available and in the "System" module has "Metatag: Verification (off)". I have no idea how to enable it.

Comment: How far did you get in the instructions?

Comment: Step 3 "Click to expand the Site Verification section (underneath Advanced)". "Site Verification" section is missing

Comment: The Metatag: Verification module is enabled?

Comment: No and I can't find a way to enable it

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by that. The Metatag: Verification module’s only dependency is Metatag. You should be able to enable this Drupal module.

Answer (score 1):

Step 2 in the guide says to install the "Metatag Verification" submodule, that's included as part of the Metatag module suite so it should already be in your site's directory structure. Given you're new to working with Drupal, the [user guide's page on installing modules](https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/config-install.html) will help you install the module; you should read through the entire [user guide](https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html) anyway, it'll help you understand how the whole system works.